# Merging multiple rows in a column into single row with python

Tags: python, pandas, row

I wanted to merge every four rows in a column into a single row in the next column. For the following dataframe, it will convert 16 rows to  4 rows where each row contains  values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A1': [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0]})
```

output should be,

```
A2:
1000
1100
1000
1110
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Since the second column will only have 4 rows but the first will have 16, there will be a dimension mismatch. So you will either have to save the second column in a second dataframe or repeat the A2 label for each A1 value

Besides that, this should work to get the A2 values you were looking for.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A1': [1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0]})

A2 = []

#loop through every fourth value
for i in range(0, len(df), 4):
    #get the current four values
    current_four = df.iloc[i: (i + 4)]

    #convert the values to strings to join them together
    new_entry = ''.join(map(str,list(current_four['A1'])))
    A2.append(new_entry)

result_df = pd.DataFrame({'A2': A2})
```

Comment: that will work. Thanks though.

Comment: Another question, At the output if the row starts with 0 then it doensn't appear at the beginning. For example, [0,1,1,0] -> 110. how can I solve that?

Comment: Just edited to fix this. The conversion to an int before adding it to the dataframe was turning '0110' to 110, so you just need to use A2.append(new_entry) instead of A2.append(int(new_entry))